# Display a contact list with Ionic + Cordova + AngularJS without using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to display my contact list on my smartphone. I can achieve this but the only way to ask for the list to display is to call the findcontact() function with a ng-click.

I tried to call the findcontact() function from within the controller but with no luck.

How can I display this list without having to click on this button ?

First the javascript, then the HTML.

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('contacts2', ['$scope', 'PhoneContactsFactory', function($scope, PhoneContactsFactory) {
    
 $scope.findContact = function()
    {
        PhoneContactsFactory.find().then(function(contacts)
        {
            $arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
            {
    $arr.push({name: contacts[i].name.formatted})
   }
            $scope.contacts = $arr;
        });
  
    };
}])

.factory("PhoneContactsFactory", ['$q', function($q)
{
    return {
        find: function()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer(); // asynchronous
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.multiple = true;
            var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
            
            navigator.contacts.find(fields, 
    function(contacts){ deferred.resolve(contacts); }, //onsuccess
    function(error){ deferred.reject(error); }, // onerror
    options);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
 };
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="contacts2">
    <button ng-click="findContact()">Push 2</button>
 <ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
       {{contact.name}}
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </div>
```

Thanks a lot !

yts

Comment: Can't you just move the code to the link() function?

Answer (score 2):

finally a trivial solution came from a discussion on the #ionic irc chan. The problem was a race condition. As the contact list was only displayed when the page is reloaded by cordova I thought the problem might be related to plugins not ready at the first loading.

So I updated my controller code, with $ionicPlatform.ready(function()) and it now works nicely.

The latest code is here : https://github.com/lennycartier/ionic-contactlist

For a very interesting article about this (simple) problem see raymondcamden.com blog.

And my little article on this : http://www.datanotes.org/13-ionic-framework-and-deviceready

yts